# How to get the most recent shared AWS RDS snapshot by id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 databases on AWS RDS, one for `stage` and one for `production` across 2 accounts. I am trying to copy the data in `production` to `stage` every x days. My plan was to make a copy of the most recent automatic backup snapshot in `production` and share it to the `stage` account before creating the database in `stage` using the shared snapshot from `production`. Everything was going right until I ran into what I believe is a bug but it could easily be that I made a mistake.

When I tried to get the most recent, shared, snapshot with an id of `abcd` in Terraform with `data "aws_db_snapshot"`, I got no results.

```
data "aws_db_snapshot" "latest_prod_snapshot" {
  db_instance_identifier = "abcd"
  snapshot_type          = "shared"
  include_shared         = "true"
  most_recent            = "true"
}
```

Then I decided to try out AWS CLI. When I run this...

`aws rds describe-db-snapshots --snapshot-type shared --include-shared`

... I get this...

```
{
    "DBSnapshots": [
        {
            "MasterUsername": "root", 
            "LicenseModel": "general-public-license", 
            "InstanceCreateTime": "2018-01-13T00:00:00.000Z", 
            "Engine": "mysql", 
            "VpcId": "vpc-0000000000000000", 
            "SourceRegion": "us-east-1", 
            "AllocatedStorage": 20, 
            "Status": "available", 
            "PercentProgress": 100, 
            "SourceDBSnapshotIdentifier": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:000000000000:snapshot:rds:abcd-2020-01-13-00-00", 
            "DBSnapshotIdentifier": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:000000000000:snapshot:rds:abcd-2020-01-13-00-00", 
            "DBSnapshotArn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:000000000000:snapshot:rds:abcd-2020-01-13-00-00", 
            "EngineVersion": "5.6.41", 
            "ProcessorFeatures": [], 
            "OptionGroupName": "default:mysql-5-6", 
            "SnapshotCreateTime": "2020-01-13T00:00:00.000Z", 
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1b", 
            "StorageType": "gp2", 
            "Encrypted": false, 
            "IAMDatabaseAuthenticationEnabled": false, 
            "DbiResourceId": "db-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", 
            "SnapshotType": "shared", 
            "Port": 3306, 
            "DBInstanceIdentifier": "abcd"
        }
    ]
}
```

... which is what I expected. Looking at the response, I would expect the db instance id to be `abcd` but when I run this...

`aws rds describe-db-snapshots --snapshot-type shared --include-shared --db-instance-identifier abcd`

... or this...

`aws rds describe-db-snapshots --snapshot-type shared --include-shared --filters Name=db-instance-id,Values=abcd`

... I get this...

```
{
    "DBSnapshots": []
}
```

... which is not what I would have expected. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I looked through their documentation but I may have missed something.

Comment: I agree. I have managed to reproduce your results. Basically, when a DB Instance ID is specified for a Shared snapshot, the result set is empty. The same commands work fine in the "same" (non-shared) account. This happens for both the AWS CLI and boto3. If you have a Support Plan with AWS, you should create a support ticket with this information.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a support plan where I can get technical support.

Comment: You are not alone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233735/error-listing-tags-for-rds-db-cluster-snapshot

Answer (score 1):

While we wait for AWS to fix this. Here are some things you can do as workaround:

1. In the `stage` account copy the shared snapshot and use the copy instead of the shared.
2. In Terraform, rollback to an older provider version.

`2.27` works for me

```
provider "aws" {
  version                 = "2.27.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per AWS Support, DBInstanceIdentifier is used to display results of only the snapshots owned by calling customer, and therefore does not return results of the shared snapshots. In order to filter and display only the shared snapshots using the DBInstanceIdentifier, --query may be used to filter by the DBInstanceIdentifier value:

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --snapshot-type shared --include-shared --query "DBSnapshots[?DBInstanceIdentifier=='abcd']"
```