# error listing tags for RDS DB Cluster Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

So I have a workflow that looks like this:

[Production]

1. Snap cluster
2. Share snapshot to Staging

[Staging]

3. Create new cluster out of shared snapshot

I'm using terraform so my config will look like this (for brevity I excluded other attributes and resources)

```
data "aws_db_cluster_snapshot" "development_final_snapshot" {
  db_cluster_identifier = "arn:prod_id:my_cluster"
  include_shared                 = true
  most_recent                    = true
  snapshot_type                  = "shared"
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora" {
  snapshot_identifier  = "${data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.development_final_snapshot.id}"
}
```

Then I get this error

```
error listing tags for RDS DB Cluster Snapshot (arn:prod_id:my_cluster): 
InvalidParameterValue: The specified resource name does not match an RDS resource in this region.
```

This was working fine last week :(.

Comment: Sounds similar to: [How to get the most recent shared AWS RDS snapshot by id?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60085106/174777)

Comment: @edmamerto Are you able to get this working?